# no such file to load -- sensu-handler

Tags: ruby, rubygems, sensu

Just getting started with Sensu and running into the following error trying to test out a handler:

```
/etc/sensu/handlers$ ./hipchat.rb
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- sensu-handler (LoadError)
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
from ./hipchat.rb:4
```

The handler is the [Hipchat handler from Github](https://github.com/sensu/sensu-community-plugins/blob/master/handlers/notification/hipchat.rb). I have the handler hipchat.rb and hipchat.json in the same directory (/etc/sensu/handlers) with the API key and room set up, but no messages appear there when I deliberately trigger a critical error that should fire:

```
 {"timestamp":"2014-07-15T22:32:38.936944+0000","level":"info","message":"handling event","event":{"client":{"name":"foo.bar.com","address":"10.101.105.41","subscriptions":["test","webservers","base"],"timestamp":1405463543},"check":{"handlers":["default","hipchat"],"command":"/etc/sensu/plugins/check-procs.rb -p cron -C 1 ","interval":60,"subscribers":["webservers"],"name":"cron_check","issued":1405463558,"executed":1405463558,"output":"CheckProcs CRITICAL: Found 0 matching processes; cmd /cron/\n","status":2,"duration":0.571,"history":["0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2"]},"occurrences":12,"action":"create"},"handler":{"type":"pipe","command":"cat","name":"stdout"}}

 $ which -a ruby
 /usr/bin/ruby
 $ which gem
 /usr/bin/gem
 $ ruby --version
 ruby 1.8.7 (2010-01-10 patchlevel 249) [x86_64-linux]
 $ lsb_release -a
 Description:   Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS
 Codename:  lucid
```

Sensu seems to be running happily otherwise.  If I set EMBEDDED_RUBY=true and run

```
$ /opt/sensu/embedded/bin/ruby hipchat.rb
```

I get no output, but when I quit ruby I get:

```
^C/opt/sensu/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sensu-plugin-0.3.0/lib/sensu-plugin/utils.rb:23:in `read': Interrupt
from /opt/sensu/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sensu-plugin-0.3.0/lib/sensu-plugin/utils.rb:23:in `read_event'
from /opt/sensu/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sensu-plugin-0.3.0/lib/sensu-handler.rb:53:in `block in <class:Handler>'
/opt/sensu/embedded/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:53:in `require': cannot load such file -- hipchat (LoadError)
from /opt/sensu/embedded/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:53:in `require'
from hipchat.rb:5:in `<main>'
```

Obviously, Ruby isn't my first language.
What do I need to do to get Ruby to find/use sensu-handler?

EDIT:

Noticed this in the sensu server logs, too:

```
 {"timestamp":"2014-07-15T23:33:17.827369+0000","level":"info","message":"handler output","handler":{"type":"pipe","command":"/etc/sensu/handlers/hipchat.rb","severities":["critical","ok"],"name":"hipchat"},"output":"/opt/sensu/embedded/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:53:in `require': cannot load such file -- hipchat (LoadError)\n"}
```

What file is hipchat.rb referring to when it's trying to require 'hipchat' on line 5? hipchat.json?

Answer (score 3):

Since nobody took the free points by answering the question.  The answer is:

Use the embedded Ruby from Sensu to install the Hipchat gem:

```
sudo /opt/sensu/embedded/bin/gem install hipchat
```

Woulda been nice is anything anywhere had mentioned there was a Hipchat gem.  As I mentioned, I'm new to Ruby so this was non-obvious.

As for the non-Sensu Ruby problems, looks like I just need to find a way to install Ruby 1.9.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue but with using the sensu mailer. I found out it had to with rvm not playing nice with embedded sensu ruby. Essentially, I had to re-install sensu master server with rvm using system ruby.

```
rvm --default use system
```

After reinstalling sensu, I was able to install needed gems that would actually install into the sensu embedded ruby gem folder.

```
/opt/sensu/embedded/bin/gem install mail --no-ri --no-rdoc -v 2.5.4
```